# Add the option "automatic return" to my cells C#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

i want to add the option "automatic return" (in french "retour automatique à la ligne") to all actives cells in my Excel file. 
For now i have try a lot of things but i can't find this option...

Can you maybe help me? Here is what i have:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
wb = app.Workbooks.Open(PathWrite.Replace(".csv", ".xlsx"), Type.Missing, 
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
Excel._Worksheet workSheet = app.ActiveSheet;
for (int x = 1; x <= 7; x++)
{
     Excel.Range range = workSheet.Columns[x];
     range.VerticalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;
     range.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

     workSheet.Columns.UseStandardWidth = 30;
     Excel.Borders border = range.Borders;
     border.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
     border.Weight = Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin;
     border.ColorIndex = Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic;
     range.AutoFit();
}
```

For resume, i want to format a file that i created by converting a .csv file  into .xlsx file. I'm not used to Office Interop so don't hesitate to tell me if something is bad and the reason for having this disgusting *for* loop is that i don't succeed to select only the 7 first columns with one command.. It's only my second day working on Excel by C# so be indulgent please. For my language too i think, i'm not really good with english.

Thanks for reading this

Comment: When you say "automatic return" do you mean when you finish typing in the last cell on a row, you move to the first cell on the next row?

Comment: @AshleyPillay No, i mean that when you open a file Excel normally, in the option on the top, you have an option "automatic return" for when the text is bigger than the cell, Excel make the cell taller for that all the text is visible but it's always the same cell in the same row. This is the option that i want to add to all cells in my file because i have a lot of text in each cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the setting you want is *word wrap*:

```
range.WrapText = True
```